# How to set background of selected/unselected Button in the XML file

Tags: android, xml, button

I have custom buttons that are supposed to have different backgrounds depending if they are selected or not selected. I want to know if there is a way to state this in the XML file. I have a button for Celsius and a button for Fahrenheit. I want it to work where if one is selected, it stays "pressed" and unable to be clicked, while the other button can be pressed.

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/celsiusButton"
            android:text="C"
            android:background="@drawable/button_unpressed_shape"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fahrenheitButton"
            android:text="F"
            android:background="@drawable/button_unpressed_shape"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:gravity="center" />
```

The Celsius button is defaulted to selected. I try working on it like this in my code, but it just seems to messy:

```
    tempText = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.temperatureId );
    celsiusButton = (Button) findViewById( R.id.celsiusButton );
    celsiusButton.setBackgroundDrawable( getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.button_pressed_shape ) );
    celsiusButton.setClickable( false );

    celsiusButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if( hasRead ) {
                    celsiusButton.setBackgroundDrawable( getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.button_pressed_shape ) );
                    celsiusButton.setClickable( false );
                    fahrenheitButton.setBackgroundDrawable( getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.button_unpressed_shape ) );
                    fahrenheitButton.setClickable( true );
                    temperature = ( ( ( temperature - 32 ) * 5 ) / 9 );
                    tempText.setText( Double.toString( temperature ).substring( 0, ( Double.toString( temperature ).length() - 2 ) ) + " C" );
            }
        }       
    });

    fahrenheitButton = (Button) findViewById( R.id.fahrenheitButton );
    fahrenheitButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick( View v ) {
            if( hasRead ) {
                fahrenheitButton.setBackgroundDrawable( getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.button_pressed_shape ) );
                celsiusButton.setBackgroundDrawable( getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.button_unpressed_shape ) );
                celsiusButton.setClickable( true );
                fahrenheitButton.setClickable( false );
                temperature = ( ( temperature * 9 ) / 5 ) + 32;
                tempText.setText( Double.toString( temperature ).substring( 0, ( Double.toString( temperature ).length() - 2 ) ) + "° F" );
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If it's selected or not selected you should use a toggle button https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html

Be aware that there are still 4 states for that

You define them in a selector like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/likeactivepressed" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/likeinitialpressed"/>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/likeon"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/likeinitial"/>
</selector>
```

Then define it in your button like this

```
  android:background="@drawable/like_button"
```

**Edit**

You could actually just use 1 button for your use. Alternatively you can use 2 radio buttons

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton.html

Comment: Thanks, that looks real nice.

Answer (score 6):

This is used to change color of button on pressed or focused
write this code in your drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Button Focused-->
    <item   android:state_focused="true"
            android:state_pressed="false"
            android:drawable="@drawable/login_hover"
            />
<!-- Button Focused Pressed-->
    <item   android:state_focused="true"
            android:state_pressed="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/login_hover"
            />
<!-- Button Pressed-->
    <item   android:state_focused="false"
            android:state_pressed="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/login_hover"
            />
<!-- Button Default Image-->
    <item   android:drawable="@drawable/login_bg"/>

</selector
```

http://nishantvnair.wordpress.com/2010/10/05/change-color-of-button-on-click-android/

Comment: For this to work you have to do this yourButton.setFocusableInTouchMode(true)

Answer (score 4):

To change background image:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   if(v == ButtonName) {
     ButtonName.setImageResource(R.drawable.ImageName);
   }
}
```

Or, using an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true"
   android:drawable="@drawable/login_selected" /> <!-- pressed -->
  <item android:state_focused="true"
   android:drawable="@drawable/login_mouse_over" /> <!-- focused -->
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/login" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

In OnClick, just add this code:

```
ButtonName.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ImageName));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can select a `Drawable` based on the state of the `View` that is rendering it.

This is the exact purpose of a `Selector` type of drawable. See examples and guide here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Basically, each `item` of a selector defines which states have which values. It also defines which drawable represents this set of values.

Next, you can set state of a `View` from the code, eg.

```
celsiusButton.setPressed(true);
```

This is great in practice because you're separating UI settings from the model/controller. Maintaining large sets of drawables comes easier when the code isn't responsible for changing the UI of your application in a direct way.

An example of my working selector is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_background_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_background_focused" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_background_default" />

</selector>
```

This example renders a button background depending on it's state.