# Press effect on normal button Android studio

Tags: android

I have a normal button in android studio and want to make it orange when pressed 
sorry if its an overused question the other answers really confused me..

```
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:text="Buttonnn"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Small"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#FF000000"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />
```

Comment: The solution at [How to set background of selected/unselected Button in the XML file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14325317/how-to-set-background-of-selected-unselected-button-in-the-xml-file) should be clear, especially and it links to the documentation that also explains how to implement it.

Comment: Thanks for that also can i use a color instead of a background image?

Comment: Try `<item android:state_pressed="true"><shape><solid android:color="@color/orange"/></shape></item>`

Comment: Cheers btw i just added some colors to the color.xml and referenced them Cheers.